# What is wrong in my code? How can I update the product_info?

Tags: php, html, session, post

This is my code and I can't figure out how to update the product_info:

```
include_once "dbconnect.php";
session_start();

$p_id = $_SESSION['rbtn'];
$p_name=securethis( $_POST['p_name']);
$p_unit=securethis( $_POST['p_unit']);
$p_price=securethis( $_POST['p_price']);
$p_details=securethis($_POST['p_details']);

$query= "UPDATE product_info SET p_name=$p_name,p_unit=$p_unit,p_price=$p_price,p_details=$p_details,p_directory=hi WHERE p_id=$p_id";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) ;

$_SESSION['rbtn'] = "";
header("Location: admin.php");
```

Comment: How do you know this is not working. Is it not displaying any errors>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the query like this-

```
$query= "UPDATE product_info SET p_name='$p_name',p_unit='$p_unit',p_price='$p_price',p_details='$p_details',p_diretory='hi' WHERE p_id='$p_id'";
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: although the OP accepted this as being the correct solution, is considered as being a very low-quality answer and does not "explain" *why* their code failed in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Your used query should be in valid format to execute by MySQL . May be there are some columns in product_info table are VARCHAR type like as p_name . So use single quote (') to create a valid query . You can also check it by echoing your query and execute this on MYSQL prompt . It will tell the exact problem.

```
echo $query= "UPDATE product_info SET p_name=$p_name,p_unit=$p_unit,p_price=$p_price,p_details=$p_details,p_directory=hi WHERE p_id=$p_id";
```

and execute the the printed query directly to the MYSQL shell .